How do I allow Google Maps to use my location but not Google Search?
A few months ago, the URL for Google Maps was changed from https://maps.google.com to https://www.google.com/maps, making it a sub-directory instead of a sub-domain. This means that if I give Google Maps permission to use my location, my location data will also be shared when using other Google services like Google Search, Drive, Meet, etc.
I only want Google to have access to my location when using Maps. Any other time I want location access blocked. To be clear, I am aware Google can use the location data gathered from Maps within their other services. However, I want to limit the location data I share so it is only shared when necessary, IE: when I am using Google Maps.
How do I share my location with Google Maps without sharing my location when using other Google services?
I am using Google Chrome and am logged in to my Google account.

Short Answer
To enable your browser's share  Location privilege for  Maps but not Search, try:

Only provide browser Location privileges on a per-visit basis not globally based on site.
Browse Maps/Search in a different web browser or one in a Guest session and manage the settings differently.
See if an extension exists to help with your end goal.


The article you linked to, "Google changed Google Maps URL: Your location data is no longer safe", is almost 2 years old unnecessarily alarmist.
The concern it is excited about is about access to your "precise" location by websites via the Browser's Location option.
Your concern about cross-contamination of browser Location privileges between Google Search and Maps is mostly misplaced because you are actively logged into  both Maps and Search in the same browser, presumably Chrome and presumably sync'ing your Chrome browser profile.
You may also be using one or more mobile devices at that location logged in to your Google account.
The Location privilege is better described as a 'Precise' Location privilege and likely offers more privacy value for non-Google websites.
You already shared your precise location with (large "G") Google when you shared it in Maps.
If you want to actively interfere with Google's aggregated picture of "you" (who you are, where you are, and what you do) it requires much more than simply choosing to share precise location data in one tab/session/day but not in another, whether the apps use matching domains or not.
PS: The location data that Chrome browser shares with sites you allow is to is retrieved by Chrome from Google Location Services...
